# Can Python code be within a CSS file like HTML?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

So um I'm using Flask to build a simple website and I want to change the colour design of the HTML template based on certain changes of a variable.

For example: if counter=1 then change the CSS variable: '--theme-color' to red, to blue if counter==2, and so on.
I know we can use python code in HTML using the wrapper {% code %}. Is there anything similar for CSS or any workarounds?
I don't know JS and so I'm hoping to make it entirely based on python.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can't use python in html, you can use python to generate html via what appears to be a jinja template

Comment: Why do you don't want use wrapper?

Comment: I don't know Flask but ***if*** you can use python in HTML then you can just use inline CSS elements.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

Comment: You should use jinja if else and use inline css in html for it. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use jinja2 with variables to access different styles. 
 For example:

```
{% if counter = 1 %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% else %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, will try it out! Thankss!

Comment: @Titan mark answer as correct please if you can